# group_by not working when using jsonapi-serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem when using Model.all.group_by { |t| t.category }

I want to get the final result from data like this :

`[{ products: [ "hardware" : [{}, {}], "software"  : [{}, {}] ] }]`

But I have a problem, namely:

`"#<FastJsonapi::MandatoryField: id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec>"`

I need the key of the category to be displayed on the front end, can anyone help?

I want the front-end not to work to process this.

I do the front-end work to sort the array according to its categories.

Comment: Your question is unclear for me. `[{ products: [ "hardware" : [{}, {}], "software"  : [{}, {}] ] }]` — why do you decide to pass to frontend arrays of empty hashes? `Model.all.group_by { |t| t.category }` — how it's correspond with those structure? How do you apply this serializer in your code? So many questions. You should update the question to make it understandable with minimal example. BTW `.all.group_by { |t| t.category }` has very bad performance, especially if there are millions of records

Comment: Using `group_by` on collections of models is usually not a very good idea as you'll end up loading the entire table to then iterate through them in Ruby and then apply some sort of paging. This creates obvious performance and memory issues once the table size is non-trivial. It's better to use `group` to add GROUP BY clause to the SQL query and then apply limits and offsets to get the relevant data.