# How to group products by category and render the response in JSONAPI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m new to Rails, I’m using the `jsonapi-serializer` gem and I want to get data on all products grouped by category in JSONAPI format.

My models:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :products, through: :categorizations

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :name, uniqueness: true
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 100 }
end
```

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  include ImageUploader::Attachment(:image)

  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: :categorizations

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :price, numericality: { other_than: 0 }, presence: true
  validates :image, presence: true
end
```

```
class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :product

  validates :category_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :product_id }
  validates :product_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: :category_id }
end
```

My serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :name, :description

  has_many :products, serializer: ProductSerializer
  has_many :categorizations, serializer: CategorizationSerializer
end
```

```
class ProductSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :title, :body, :price, :image

  has_many :categories, serializer: CategorySerializer
  has_many :categorizations, serializer: CategorizationSerializer
end
```

```
class CategorizationSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  belongs_to :category, serializer: CategorySerializer
  belongs_to :product, serializer: ProductSerializer
end
```

My controller:

```
def index
  @grouped_list = Product.joins(:categories).group('categories.id')
                            .pluck('categories.id', 'json_agg(products)')
                            .to_h
  render json: ProductSerializer.new(@grouped_list, include: 
   [:categories]).serializable_hash.to_json,
           status: :ok, code: '200'
end
```

In RSpec I create a category, a product and categorize them and send a get 'api/v1/products/ request, after which I display the JSON parse in the console (so far). But I get this error:

```
Failure/Error:
       render json: ProductSerializer.new(@grouped_list, include: [:categories]).serializable_hash.to_json,
              status: :ok, code: '200'
     
     FastJsonapi::MandatoryField:
       id is a mandatory field in the jsonapi spec
```

I read that due to JSONAPI specification, the serializer must have a resource ID. They offered a solution in the form of the `jsonapi.rb` gem, but there were only simple filtering and sorting functions.if I use
`render json: @grouped_list, status: :ok, code: '200'`
then the output is more similar to the truth

```
{"1"=>[{"id"=>1, "title"=>"Remote Lifter", "body"=>"Bryntforge Disc HD Viewer", "price"=>4.8, "image_data"=>"{\"id\":\"94bbe9ff6ce2f4b7aeea3af4afcc43da.webp\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"product_image.webp\",\"size\":12612,\"mime_type\":\"image/webp\"}}", "created_at"=>"2024-01-02T11:22:29.678361", "updated_at"=>"2024-01-02T11:22:29.681054"}], "2"=>[{"id"=>2, "title"=>"Side Filter", "body"=>"Cobalt Auto Bridge", "price"=>6.7, "image_data"=>"{\"id\":\"6dbaed566c1781af28345e5887462213.webp\",\"storage\":\"store\",\"metadata\":{\"filename\":\"product_image.webp\",\"size\":12612,\"mime_type\":\"image/webp\"}}", "created_at"=>"2024-01-02T11:22:29.702798", "updated_at"=>"2024-01-02T11:22:29.704907"}]}
```

but I need the answer in JSONAPI.

Please suggest me some solution using JSONAPI-format. I saw a similar problem here:

[group_by not working when using jsonapi-serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77248080/group-by-not-working-when-using-jsonapi-serializer)

Comment: I am a bit confused on this. Can you explain why you are not rendering Categories with their included Products instead? This would create the desired grouping and maintain spec.

Comment: Do you offer this option?
`@grouped_list = Category.joins(:products).group('categories.id'); render json: CategorySerializer.new(@grouped_list, include: [:products]).serializable_hash.to_json `

Comment: I was thinking more like `CategorySerializer.new(Category.joins(:products), include: [:products]).serializable_hash.to_json`

Comment: Perhaps this is exactly what should be done. There is not much information about this in my language segment, so I am also confused. Thanks a lot! Do you happen to have any thoughts (if I haven't bored you yet) on how to test such queries in RSpec? I thought about using `assings`, but that's for controllers, not requests.